# MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported tried all solutions

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

i am having a issue with loading styles. I currently have a public folder and have all my css inside the folder. i get a error Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. I have tried most of the solutions that i found online but they dont seem to help my situation. I am new to stackoverflow this is my cry for help

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));





    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/fontAwesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/hero-slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/owl-carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/templatemo-style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/lightbox.css"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: You aren't setting the `link`s `type` attribute to `"text/css"`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: i am using text/css

Comment: not int the code that you provided. Please post all relevant code

Comment: @Wendelin just tried that still nothing

Comment: the original file did not include node the minute i used node it stopped working. i made a new file public and moved all the css into that file and changed all the paths

Comment: This seems like a server-side issue. The server isn't setting the MIME type of `.css` files to `text/css`.

Comment: Have you tried GOING to the links the css is set to? i've had this happen if i linked it wrong and the application had a 404 error page for you.